# Change Angular 2 Maps Marker Icon when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using Angular 2 Maps with an Ionic 2 app. Can anyone help me out on how to change the style of a marker when it is clicked (size, color, etc) and then change it back when another marker or the map is clicked. I have a click event attached to the map and the markers. I an able to get access to the Object associated with the marker and the index of it. Here is the code for my map.

html

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (mapClick)="clickedMap()">
    <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let base of bases; let i = index" [latitude]="base.location.latitude" [longitude]="base.location.longitude"
      (markerClick)="clickedMarker(base, i)"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { BaseDetailsPage } from '../base-details/base-details';
import { BasesProvider } from '../../providers/bases-provider';

declare var google;

/*
  Generated class for the BasesMap page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-bases-map',
  templateUrl: 'bases-map.html'
})
export class BasesMapPage {

  bases: any;
  baseData: any;
  baseName: string;
  footer: boolean;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  zoom: number;
  //markerIconUrl: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public basesProvider: BasesProvider) {
    this.baseName = '';
    this.footer = false;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    loader.present().then(() => {
      this.basesProvider.loadAllBases().then(data => {
        this.bases = data;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.bases.length; i++) {
          this.bases[i].markerIcon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
        }
        console.log(this.bases);

      }).then(() => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
          this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
          this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          this.zoom = 3;
          //this.markerIconUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
        }).catch((error) => {
          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'Error getting location',
            duration: 3000
          });
          toast.present();
        });
      }).then(() => {
        loader.dismiss();
      })
    });
  }

  clickedMarker(base, index) {
    console.log("====> " + index);
    this.baseData = base;
    this.baseName = base.name;
    //this.markerIconUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
    this.footer = true;
  }

  clickedMap() {
    this.footer = false;
    this.baseName = '';
  }

  baseDetails() {
    this.navCtrl.push(BaseDetailsPage, {
      id: this.baseData.id
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: usually you save all your markers in an array, then set the map on that marker to show the marker on the map, and the set the map to null on that market to delete from the map.

Comment: I don't think you are following what I want to do. Example: map has 10 markers on it and all markers are blue; user picks marker 1; marker one turns to red; user picks marker 4; marker 4 turns red and marker 1 turns blue; and so on
My markers are in an array. see code below:

Comment: <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (mapClick)="clickedMap()">
    <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let base of bases; let i = index" [latitude]="base.location.latitude" [longitude]="base.location.longitude"
      [iconUrl]="markerIconUrl" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(base, i)"></sebm-google-map-marker>
  </sebm-google-map>

Comment: on `clickedMarker` you pass the marker index `i`, use that to find your marker and update `markerIconUrl`. However you have to save the `markerIconUrl` in `bases`, so you can access it as `base.markerIconUrl`

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying; I am just not sure how to set it in the typescript controller. Not much is documented for Angular 2 maps. do you think you could help me out??

Comment: @jdubicki pls add code to your question. Adding it in the comments is not useful at all